# worklight windows 8 get device name

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to obtain device name (the "computer Name") in worklight app for environment Windows 8.

It seems that WL.Device class can't help in Windows 8 (not Phone) environment.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks, 
f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation between `WL.Device` and what you're looking for.
In Windows 8 you need to use the WinJS API.

Try the following and inspect the JavaScript Console in Visual Studio:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    getHostName();
}

function getHostName() {
    var hostNamesList = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.getHostNames();

    for (var i = 0; i < hostNamesList.length; i++) {
        var entry = hostNamesList[i];

        if (entry.type === Windows.Networking.HostNameType.domainName) {
            console.log(entry.displayName);
        }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Source: http://caioproiete.net/en/get-the-network-machine-name-in-a-windows-store-app/